# Bouncing a solid sphere from the frame boundaries

Tags: opengl

> Use of timer and glTranslate functions helps me move the sphere. But how do I bounce it back from the frame boundries?? 
>   Or is there any other way to implement the same?
>   I have tried using for loop for continuously translating the sphere and not using the timer function. In this approach I have to manually calculate the change in direction points using the glOrtho limits and the glTranstale function which in turn makes no sense.

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <GL/gl.h>
#include <GL/glu.h>
#include <GL/glut.h>
void Timer(int ex)
{ 
    glutPostRedisplay();
    glutTimerFunc(20,Timer,0);
}
void init(void) 
{   
    glEnable(GL_LIGHTING);
    glEnable(GL_LIGHT0);
    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
}
void display(void)
{
   int i,j;
   glClear (GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
   glTranslatef(0.08,0.08,0.0);
   glutSolidSphere (1.0, 20, 16);
   glFlush ();
} 
void reshape (int w, int h)
{
   glViewport (0, 0, (GLsizei) w, (GLsizei) h);
   glMatrixMode (GL_PROJECTION);
   glLoadIdentity(); 
   glOrtho (-10, 10, -10,10, -10.0, 10.0);
   glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
   glLoadIdentity();
}
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    glutInit(&argc, argv);
    glutInitDisplayMode (GLUT_SINGLE | GLUT_RGB | GLUT_DEPTH);
    glutInitWindowSize (800, 800); 
    glutInitWindowPosition (100, 100);
    glutCreateWindow (argv[0]);
    init ();
    glutDisplayFunc(display); 
    glutReshapeFunc(reshape);
    glutTimerFunc(0,Timer,0);
    glutMainLoop();
    return 0;
 }
```

Comment: This isn't really an OpenGL question so much as it is a general programming question.

Comment: Apologies if I got the wrong end here, but mathematically a sphere is a shape with its edges a uniform distance from the center. Therefore, if the distance from the center to the edge is <= the radius then it's time to bounce. Is that what you're asking?

Comment: @MIke  Three parameters to glutSolidSphere() are radius, slices and stacks. So how do i get the center postion of the sphere?

Comment: It's where you are moving it to (x, y, z) in the transform.